# If $f(a)\neq g(a)$, prove that there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)\neq g(y)$ for every $x,y\in B(a,\delta)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$ be continous functions and $a\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. If $f(a)\neq g(a)$, prove that there exists $\delta >0$ such that  $f(x)\neq g(y)$ for every $x,y\in B(a,\delta)$

**My attempt**
Let's take $\epsilon =\frac{\left \| f(a)-g(a)) \right \|}{2}$

Then, we know that f and g are continous functions. So they are continous in "a", that is:

$\exists \delta>0$ such that $\left \| f(x)-f(a) \right \|<\epsilon$ when $\left \| x-a \right \|<\delta$

$\exists \delta>0$ such that $\left \| g(y)-g(a) \right \|<\epsilon$ when $\left \| x-a \right \|<\delta$

Then

$\left | \left \| f(x) \right \|-\left \| f(a) \right \| \right |<\left \| f(x)-f(a) \right \|<\frac{\left \| f(a)-g(a)) \right \|}{2}$

$\left | \left \| g(y) \right \|-\left \| g(a) \right \| \right |<\left \| g(y)-g(a) \right \|<\frac{\left \| f(a)-g(a)) \right \|}{2}$

Removing the absolute value:

$- \left \| f(x) \right \|+\left \| f(a) \right \| < \frac{\left \| f(a)-g(a)) \right \|}{2} < \left \| f(x) \right \|-\left \| f(a) \right \| $

$- \left \| g(y) \right \|+\left \| g(a) \right \| < \frac{\left \| f(a)-g(a)) \right \|}{2} < \left \| g(y) \right \|-\left \| g(a) \right \|$

But then I don't know what else to do. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to consider the continuous function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ and note that $\lVert h(a) \rVert >0$ in a neighborhood of $a$, in fact for $0<\epsilon < \lVert h(a)\rVert$ choose $\delta$ so that for $\lVert x-a\rVert <\delta $ we have $\lvert h(x) - h(a)\rVert <\epsilon$ in particular $\lVert h(x)\rVert >0$ for all such $x$.